What are the way to restrict a docker engine to specific repository?
I am searching for possible ways to restrict docker from accessing docker registries other than the one I would specify.
I have found docker access management, but that is for docker business and only work with desktop.
Are there other ways to achieve this ?

some more context is needed. is docker desktop a must? Does the user has console access to the mashiene?

This is for our CI/CD pipeline which is on jenkins, with the agent as ec2 instances.

Typically this would be solved by configuring a firewall egress policy with an allow list. That would handle not only the Docker Engine, but all other methods of downloading content from the internet that your organization has not previously approved.

Thanks for the reply. Will check the fesability of restricting our jenkins agent with the team. I also found out about https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/ but this sounds complicated to set up

Everywhere I've worked that had a strict egress policy had plenty of engineers that knew how to get around the firewall because it was easier to workaround the restrictions than to get a request approved to change them. This frequently involved copying image content to another registry or exporting/importing the image the same way that other places would use to transfer content over an air-gap. So before you get too far into the process, consider how much security will actually be improved vs engineer productivity decreased.
